# SQL displaying the right number, names

Tags: sql

I'm working on a Coffee Shop database and trying to find number of sales per item. The number comes back correctly, but instead of displaying the name of the coffee and the sales it displays all the coffee names with the correct data of the first drink, then all of the coffee names with the correct data of the second drink.

```
select p.ProductName, TotalSold = SUM(o.Quantity)
From MSProducts p, MSOrderline o
Group By p.ProductName, o.ProductID
```

[image]

Output should be...
1 FlavoredSyrup-Shot  11
2 ExtraExpresso 7
3. Americano-Small 5

Though it didn't fit on the page it continues with the quantity 5 below.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please show example table data, expected output, and what you are getting as output.

Comment: you can only group by 1 column, you are having 2 column

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! **Easier to write (without errors)**, easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lack of join condition was the cause of data duplication. This may work, provided you have ProductID in both tables.

```
select p.ProductName, SUM(o.Quantity) as TotalSold
From MSProducts p
inner join MSOrderline o
on p.ProductID = o.ProductID
Group By p.ProductName
```

Comment: That worked, we have never learned inner joins in class. Is there a way around inner join?

Comment: @DataStructors23 No, you will always be doing either an inner join, left or right outer join, or a cross join. It's best to explicitly spell out what type of join you want. When you used commas, but did not specify the two fields you were joining on, you got a cross join I think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map both the tables correctly.

```
MSProducts p, MSOrderline o
```

If you dont map then all the rows of first table will be mapped with all the rows of the second table. Please map it using the common column